# Error when evaluating SSR module /src/stores.js: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, local-storage, server-side-rendering, svelte

I'm trying to make a Svelte website that stores user info when reloading. I'm getting the following error:

`Error when evaluating SSR module /src/stores.js: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

The page loads properly (including localStorage.user and localStorage.isLoggedIn) after reloading and this error only appears at first.

Here is my `stores.js` file:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
export const user = writable(storedUser);
user.subscribe((value) => localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(value));

export const isLoggedIn = writable(localStorage.isLoggedIn === "true");
isLoggedIn.subscribe((value) => localStorage.isLoggedIn = String(value));
```

How do I fix this error (and why doesn't it show up after reloading?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I have to check if there was a browser environment before accessing localStorage (thought I'd post the answer here).

Just `import { browser } from '$app/env';`, and you can use `if (browser)`.

Here's my new `stores.js` file that *should* at least solve the error:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { browser } from '$app/env';

var storedUser = {};
if (browser) {
    storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
}
export const user = writable(storedUser);
user.subscribe((value) => {
    if (browser) {
        localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
});

var storedLogin = false;
if (browser) {
    storedLogin = (localStorage.isLoggedIn === "true");
}
export const isLoggedIn = writable(storedLogin);
isLoggedIn.subscribe((value) => {
    if (browser) {
        localStorage.isLoggedIn = String(value);
    }
    
});
```